# How do you get a running total for a partial view using MVC Core?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm still learning MVC and ASP.Net Core so any advice on practices/methods appreciated.

I have a partial view where I need to get the sum of each text box input as you enter the amount on the client before submitting. Here is a snippet of the code for the view (there are 8 inputs total):

```
            <span>Total allocated amount:</span>
            <span id="total"></span>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AllocatedPart" class="control-label">First</label>
                <input asp-for="AllocatedPart" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AllocatedPart" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AllocatedSecond" class="control-label">Second</label>
                <input asp-for="AllocatedSecond" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AllocatedSecond" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

I add this partial to my view using the following code so it has created a partial view in the page for each element from the database.

```
@foreach (item in Model)
{
  // setup id for div
  var divIdAFC = "edit" + item.ID.ToString();

  <div id="@{@divIdAFC}">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Partial/_edit", modelWithData)
  </div>
}
```

Here is the jQuery code I have that adds ALL the partial views contents across the entire page:

```
$(".form-control").each(function () {
    var rowval = $(this).val();
    var val = parseInt(rowval);
    if (!isNaN(val)) {
        total = total + val;
    }
});
console.log(total);
```

I tried the above with many combinations of selectors using the "@{@divIdAFC}" Div ID but have not had luck with a correct combination of the selectors.

How can I limit the jQuery to what is in a specific partial view? Or is there an MVC or Razor way to display the running total without calling jQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the jQuery codes in the foreach loop, then calcuate the sum of each input in target partial view. I made a simple test based on your codes.

Index View:

```
@model List<Allocated>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
// setup id for div
var divIdAFC = "edit" + item.ID.ToString();

<div id="@{@divIdAFC}">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Partial/_edit", item)
</div>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var total = 0;
            $("#@{@divIdAFC} .form-control").each(function () {

                    var rowval = $(this).val();
                    var val = parseInt(rowval);
                    if (!isNaN(val)) {
                        total = total + val;
                    }
                });
             $("#@{@divIdAFC} #total").text(total)

            $("#@{@divIdAFC} .form-control").on("change", function () {
                var total = 0;
                $("#@{@divIdAFC} .form-control").each(function () {

                    var rowval = $(this).val();
                    var val = parseInt(rowval);
                    if (!isNaN(val)) {
                        total = total + val;
                    }
                });
                $("#@{@divIdAFC} #total").text(total)
            })

        });
</script>
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model Allocated

<h1>Index</h1>
<span>Total allocated amount:</span>
<span id="total"></span>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="AllocatedPart" class="control-label">First</label>
    <input asp-for="AllocatedPart" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="AllocatedPart" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="AllocatedSecond" class="control-label">Second</label>
    <input asp-for="AllocatedSecond" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="AllocatedSecond" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Allocated> allocateds = new List<Allocated>
        {
            new Allocated{ ID = 1, AllocatedPart = "11", AllocatedSecond = "11"},
            new Allocated{ ID = 2, AllocatedPart = "22", AllocatedSecond = "22"},
            new Allocated{ ID = 3, AllocatedPart = "33", AllocatedSecond = "33"}
        };
        return View(allocateds);
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Allocated
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string AllocatedPart { get; set; }
    public string AllocatedSecond { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]